# Inter-session variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables, scope

I believe globals and superglobals die once the script or session ends. What's the best way to store an inter-session variable in PHP? In other words, I want every session to have access to a variable. (It will be a boolean for the purpose of synchronizing access to a resource on the server.) Is there a solution besides just storing the value in a file? It would be nice to keep the variable in memory...

**EDIT:**

I just want to be able to do this:

```
while ($beingused)
   sleep(5);
$beingused = true;
// Do something
```

**SOLUTION:**

Thank you all so much for your help. Here's my solution based on your input.

```
memcache_pconnect('localhost');
while (memcache_get('inuse') == 'true')
    usleep(10);
memcache_set('inuse', 'true');
// Do something
memcache_set('inuse', 'false');
```

**UPDATE**

I actually did end up going with a file solution after all. Each time a user interacts with the application, it is fed a script which changes depending on user input. I realized that the existence of the script file could double as a boolean, as was suggested in many of the responses.

Comment: What kind of a resource? is this resource being shared between users or used by only one during site visit? One example worth thousand words.

Comment: Well, it's an application running on the server. Each user will be interacting with the same instance of the application via shell_exec() commands. The commands complete very quickly, so collisions will be rare, but I want to make sure of that. The boolean would indicate whether or not another user is using the application. If so, the script could wait a few milliseconds and then try again.

Comment: That's still rather vague. Are you looking for a *configuration setting*? A semi-permanent entry in a *database*? A *semaphore/lock/token*? Is that a user specific setting, a machine specific setting or a global setting?

Comment: So you're looking for a *lock/token*? In that case, maybe you should rather be looking into a different architecture, if that's possible, like a queue/worker solution.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of writing a daemon but it all just seems like overkill. Maybe I'll just have a file on the server with a 1 or 0 stored in it :-) Is there seriously no simple way of doing this? It seems like I should be able to set $_SERVER['foo'] or something (but I know you can't do that...)

Comment: isn't using memcache to make 5 seconds sleep a bit overkill?

Comment: Oh, I thought it was milliseconds...

Comment: I changed sleep(5) to usleep(10) - 10 milliseconds not 5 seconds!

Comment: +1 for complete solution and updating your original question - interesting answers.

Comment: late to the party, but if that can helps someone, just look to my solution posted here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31490699/4098311

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use an empty file with certain name (like PID files in Linux). Before executing the command the script checks whether the file exists, and if not, it creates the file. After the shell script is executed, remove the file. But be careful with the file system cache.

Another fast option is to store the flag in the in-memory database like memcache or Redis.

Comment: OP specifically requested "besides just storing the value in a file".

Comment: danielfaraday requests a boolean variable. That's what PID file can do - if the file exists => TRUE, the shell script is running. If it doesn't exist - FALSE, the script is not running. No need to write something into the file.

Comment: I think memcache sounds like the most reasonable solution. The others sound just a bit hacky to me (filesystems and databases aren't meant to store run-time variables)...Thanks for the info. I'm going to look into memcache.

Comment: @Steve the op has quite vague idea of the matter. You may consider yourslf free of such a ridiculous restrictions. File is okay. +1

Comment: A PID and memcache are both good solutions, so I accepted this answer. Though the other answers are helpful as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want according to your question is to use "**in-memory database**" like [**SQlite in-memory database**](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html), or a database created using [**MySQL Memory Storage engine**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html) etc.

But I am not sure is it worth to use an in-memory database for saving just a one variable.

See more details : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database

**EDIT:**

After OP's edit, It seems what he needs is to acquire lock before doing an specific task.
Then I think you can also use these php **semaphore** related functions for that.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sem-get.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sem-acquire.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sem-get.php

Comment: @danielfaraday See the update about semaphore. But still there was nothing wrong with my original post for down-voting. As you also have commented in the below post about in-memory database.

Answer (score 0):

For saving across browsers: use a cookie.  To access them use `$_COOKIE[]` and `set_cookie()`.

For saving on the server: use a database field.

**UPDATE**

Despite the downvotes, and after your update, it seems you could just set a boolean in a database and check its value accordingly.  Surely the page has an entry in a database - a node, or a log, or something.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I ithink that a reason is that the cookies is not a solution for the issue. The database (this usually mean relational database) would solve the issue, but it is rather slow and resource consuming.

Answer (score 0):

One of the PHP principle is *SHARE NOTHING*. That means you cannot share anything between two PHP execution/process/request handling. Every shared thing must be shared outside of PHP.

For a same-user thing you have the session. For general sharing, in classical LAMP installs you have the database. But you could also use the filesystem (semaphores, locks). Using the database to put application locks is a classical thing but it may stress bad a classical Relationnal database where write operations are quite slow. Some NOSQL storage engines like Redis have very fast locking operation support.

Comment: Thanks - I think I will be going with an in-memory database solution. It makes the most sense...

Comment: thanks for your thanks but I think this does not deserve a -1

Comment: I didn't downvote (in fact I'm not allowed to downvote yet...) EDIT: NM - apparently I did get that privilege. +1